# Eloquent return elements only when last related element is older than 30 days?

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm new to programming world and I use laravel. I have have `Post` model, every user can have more posts. For for all posts I have `hasMany` relation but this is related to posts, and I need inverse logic.

I don't know how can I get only users which last post is older then 30 days? I need them for email notification.

Can somebody give me some inputs please?

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

So it should be something like this:

```
User::whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('created_at', '<=', now()->subDays(30);
})->get()
```

Comment: also you can change `where` to `whereDate` to compare dates and ignore time

Comment: I think there is something wrong because it returns me always same result, even If I change dates.